# Custom action after authentication (un)seccessful, and HTTP Basic authentication with REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

Referring my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043661) conserning Spring Security and REST, I have made some progress, but still have some questions.

1. As I said before, users will log in to my REST webservice by POSTing `someaddres.com/rest/login` with HTTP Basic authentication. I still don't know how to accomplish that, but I have configured my app to use `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter`, what remains is the actual mappings or should I make separate @Controller (I'm using Spring MVC for REST mappings)? I'd appreciate an example.
2. Secondly, as I said before, I would like to do some custom actions after login is succesfull or not (some kind of log - who, when and from where tried to log in and log out). I already tried to implement `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler` with success, and `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler` with no success, because I can't get username that was used to log in from anywhere, because `AuthenticationException#getAuthentication` method is deprecated. What is more shoud I subclass `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and override it's `onSuccessfulAuthentication` and `onUnsuccessfulAuthentication`, because these methods appear to be empty?
3. What is the best way to implement password recovery? I thought about simple posting some resource which would generate new password and send it by email.
4. How to configure Security to generate token which will be stored in session valid for let's say next 10 minutes after last action? Is it possible NOT to use cookies and store everything on server side?

Here are my security beans:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <sec:http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/*" />
        <sec:custom-filter position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" />
        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" invalidate-session="true"/>
    </sec:http>
    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>
    <bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="rms-rest" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="pl.bcichecki.rms.handlers.impl.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl" />
    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="pl.bcichecki.rms.handlers.impl.AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl" />
    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="pl.bcichecki.rms.handlers.impl.LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl" />
</beans>
```

I appreciate your help.